# How to Create a Disposable class

Tags: c#

I have this 'PlayerClass' class and every time I instantiate it I need to dispose of it, including the fields inside that class. Is there a way to do it? This is my class:

```
internal class PlayerClass 
{
    public WindowsMediaPlayer _wplayer;
}
```

How do I get to dispose of the class after using it?
I have tried to find a way on the internet but none of them are working after testing it.

I've tried this:

```
internal class PlayerClass : IDisposable
{
    public WindowsMediaPlayer _wplayer;
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Is this instance disposed?
    /// </summary>
    protected bool Disposed { get; private set; }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Dispose worker method. See http://coding.abel.nu/2012/01/disposable
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">Are we disposing? 
    /// Otherwise we're finalizing.</param>
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        Disposed = true;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks as if you're implementing `IDisposable` just for the heck of it which is not necessary for *managed code*. The garbage collector will automatically clean up behind you.

You may need to clarify in your post ***why*** you are implementing `IDisposable`.

However I believe your mistake is that `Dispose()` is not automatically called by the garbage collector. If you do implement `IDisposable` you must make sure that the code using your class either instantiates inside a `using()` statement or manually calls `.Dispose`. Otherwise your `dispose` method will never fire.

```
using(var player = new PlayerClass()){
    // Do something with player
    // player.Dispose() is called automatically when you exit this using statement.
}
```

Since you're relying on the caller to make sure `Dispose` is called you may also want to look into a `SafeHandle` (preferred) or `Finalize`.

> Because the `IDisposable.Dispose` implementation is called by the
> consumer of a type when the resources owned by an instance are no
> longer needed, you should either wrap the managed object in a
> `SafeHandle` (the recommended alternative), or you should override
> `Object.Finalize` to free unmanaged resources in the event that the
> consumer forgets to call Dispose.

Source: [`IDisposable` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx)

Using Statement
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

Answer (score 4):

Contrary to the advice of the other answers, [it is necessary **and essential** to *Dispose* of all created objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx) that implement a *Dispose()* method (ie implement IDisposable). These objects are unmanaged resources, and thus are invisible to the GC. Not disposing of them is a guaranteed memory leak.(Note that some terminology prefers a *Close()* method to a Dispose method, in which case the *Close()* method should be identical.)

Here is a best practice implementation of the IDisposable interface.

```
#region IDisposable implementation with finalizer
private bool isDisposed = false;
public void Dispose() { Dispose(true); GC.SuppressFinalize(this); }
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
  if (!isDisposed) {
    if (disposing) {
      if (_wplayer != null)     _wplayer.Dispose();
   }
  }
  isDisposed = true;
}
#endregion
```

Here are the Best Practices **Dos** and **Donts** from the MSDN link above:

- **DO** declare a protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) method to
  centralize all logic related to releasing unmanaged resources.
- **DO** implement the IDisposable interface by simply calling Dispose(true) followed by GC.SuppressFinalize(this).
- **DO NOT** make the parameterless Dispose method virtual.
- **DO NOT** declare any overloads of the Dispose method other than Dispose() and Dispose(bool).
- **DO** allow the Dispose(bool) method to be called more than once. The method might choose to do nothing after the first call.
- **AVOID** throwing an exception from within Dispose(bool) except under critical situations where the containing process has been corrupted (leaks, inconsistent shared state, etc.).
- **CONSIDER** providing method Close(), in addition to the Dispose(), if close is standard terminology in the area.

Comment: -1: About half of the first paragraph is simply not correct, for a whole bunch of reasons. For example, failing to call `Close` on the `FileStream` returned by `File.OpenRead` will not necessarily result in a memory leak because the garbage collector will eventually finalize the underlying handle object if it is no longer referenced. It will, however, have the negative side effect of keeping a lock on the file for a non-deterministic amount of time following the last use of the `FileStream` object.

Answer (score 0):

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Provides a mechanism for releasing unmanaged resources.

You do not need to dispose managed objects. .Net will lead with this for you. It is usefull when you create a interop classes which will lead with unmanaged resources, then you can dispose all objects.

Comment: -1: `FileStream` is a managed object, but it *owns* an unmanaged resource. The impact of failing to call `Dispose` (or `Close`) on this object is described in my comment on Pieter Geerkens' answer. Code does not need to declare or directly manipulate unmanaged resources in order to require careful attention to disposable objects.